# Article on using Git in DropBox Doesn't Seem to Work

Tags: git, dropbox

I found [this article](http://pivotallabs.com/users/ken/blog/articles/1637-dropbox-git-designer-luv) on using Git in Dropbox as a secondary repository. The problem when when I try to add the remote directory to my project and I get the following message:

```
git remote add file:///Users/me/Dropbox/Projects/Social-Linking dropbox
fatal: 'file:///Users/me/Dropbox/Projects/Social-Linking' is not a valid remote name
```

I followed the steps one step at a time and on a Mac.

Comment: What command gave you that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably doing

```
git remote add file:///Users/me/Dropbox/Projects/Social-Linking remotename
```

Where you should be doing

```
git remote add remotename file:///Users/me/Dropbox/Projects/Social-Linking
```

Comment: That would make sense. I figured the author didn't copy something right, but I just started with Git so I didn't know where I went wrong. I'll try that tonight when I get home.

Comment: @Mike: First thing someone should have taught you: git has a built-in help system. `git help remote` shows the help for the `remote` command.